# How to set the ignoring URL in a project that uses spring session

Tags: java, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Using spring boot to integrate spring session and spring actuator at the same time. Due to the use of prometheus monitoring, it will periodically initiate http requests for health checks and performance monitoring, but each request will generate a new session, due to the use of session sharing. The session is stored in redis, which produces a large number of useless sessions. Is there any better solution at present?

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar problem in github, and the problem is still open, but someone has already proposed a solution in the problem, the link is as follows: [Is it possible to exclude some url from the SessionRepositoryFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/244).

The sample code use filter set `SessionRepositoryFilter.FILTERED`.

```
@Component
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class ExcludeSessionRepositoryFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
      if (/* here goes your logic to exclude the session repository filter, probably depending on the request uri */) {
        httpRequest.setAttribute("org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.FILTERED", Boolean.TRUE);
      }
      filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
   }
}
```

Of course, there is another solution to complete the integration of springboot and spring security. After the integration is completed, the `SessionCreationPolicy enumeration parameters` can be adjusted due to the existence of the `SessionManagementConfigurer`, and the session creation strategy can be adjusted. Its default value is `SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED`, only after testing After logging in, the session will be synchronized to redis, which is more in line with the concept of session sharing.